# VueJS - Load different components based on the route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have this setup:

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

This is my default page. I would love it to load two different layouts (admin and public). It works fine but there is a tiny problem with the public layout. For I would love to share NAVBAR and FOOTER in all public components/pages but I don't want to copy them in all components.

**routes.js**

```
import ...
export const routes = [
// public
  { path: "",
    name: 'main',
    component: Main},
  { path: "/about",
    name: 'about',
    component: About},

// private
  { path: "/login",
    name: 'login',
    component: AdminLogin},
  { path: "/admin",
    name: 'admin',
    component: AdminHome}
]
```

so the default route is MAIN where I have the "common public" components (navbar and footer)

**Main.vue**

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="">
    <app-navbar></app-navbar>
    <div style="margin-top: 64px">

      <home></home>

      <div class="container">
        <app-footer></app-footer>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Home from './Home.vue'
  import Navbar from './shared/Navbar.vue'
  import Footer from './shared/Footer.vue'

  export default {
    components: {
      Home,
      'app-navbar': Navbar,
      'app-footer': Footer
    }
  }
</script>
```

I only want to change what is in the "middle" based on the selected route. So the default is `<home>` right now. But, how do I make it change with the routes? So when I, for example, go to ABOUT? I don't want all my pages to have this structure -> navbar, content, footer, because the navbar and footer will be redundant everywhere. Or is this the right approach, to add it everywhere?

Or can I do something like this in `Main.vue`:

```
navbar

case 
 when route == 'about' then import(about)
 else import(home)
end

footer
```

What is the best approach to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your setup one easy way to fix this issue is to use `meta` property in the router. So, for example your login route would become like this:

```
{
    path: "/login",
    name: 'login',
    meta: {
        NoNavbar: true,
        NoFooter: true
    },
    component: AdminLogin,
},
```

And then in `Main.vue` you could render the components based on these conditions:

```
<template v-if="!this.$router.resolve(this.$route.path).route.meta.NoNavbar">
    <app-navbar></app-navbar>
</template>
```

And for the footer:

```
<template v-if="!this.$router.resolve(this.$route.path).route.meta.NoFooter">
    <app-footer></app-footer>
</template>
```

**Disclaimer**

Haven't tested this locally but it can give you an idea :)

---

Here is an example on how you could make a component that acts as a layout for your application:

```
<div id="app">
    <template v-if="!this.$router.resolve(this.$route.path).route.meta.NoNavbar">
        <app-navbar></app-navbar>
    </template>

    <main>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </main>

    <template v-if="!this.$router.resolve(this.$route.path).route.meta.NoFooter">
        <app-footer></app-footer>
    </template>
</div>
```

This way you first apply the layout based on the current route, and then only the main component(s) will be rendered inside the `<main>` tag.

Comment: hi there, thx for the reply... that's not exactly what I wanted for I have plenty of paths and I would have to specify that in every single component :( I could as well use the navbar / footer in all of them too ... is there any other "generic" way? or this whole approach I am trying to do is wrong?

Comment: I wouldn't say your approach is wrong. There are different ways of doing this and you should see what suits you best. I assumed Main.vue is like a parent component in your case. Probably, you could extract that into a parent component that acts as a layout for all your application. And then use vue router to only update blocks of the page. I will add an example to the previous answer.

Comment: I was just thinking of using a flag to decide which one to show .. bec there will be one for "public" side and the other one for "private" side ...  I will try to do it with a flag 

`v-if="page==public" 
....
v-else-if="page==private"
....
v-else`

with that, I will have it only once at one place (I hope :D) and wouldn't have to manage it on multiple places

Comment: and yes, Main.vue acts like a base layout where everything else would be projected